# Linq to Entities return All Rows

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities, code-first

In my winform application i use following code to find a user:

```
   var findUser =
                userService.Find(
                    u => u.UserName == UserNameTextBox.Text.Trim() && u.Password == PasswordTextBox.Text.Trim() && u.IsActive);
```

And find method implemented as a generic method in my service layer:

```
public virtual TEntity Find(Func<TEntity, bool> predicate)
{
    return _tEntities.Where(predicate).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

When i executed this the following sql code generate and send to sql server:

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Extent1].[FirstName] AS [FirstName], 
[Extent1].[LastName] AS [LastName], 
[Extent1].[UserName] AS [UserName], 
[Extent1].[Password] AS [Password], 
[Extent1].[IsAdmin] AS [IsAdmin], 
[Extent1].[IsActive] AS [IsActive], 
[Extent1].[RowVersion] AS [RowVersion]
FROM [dbo].[Users] AS [Extent1]
```

What is the problem and how can i fix theme?

Comment: Your find method should be declared as  `public virtual TEntity Find(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)`

Comment: @nemesv: That belongs into the answer section below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Where` function has multiple overloads defined on multiple types as an extension method.

With the `Func<TEntity, bool> predicate` you are invoking the [`Enumerable.Where`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803.aspx) which evaluates your filtering on client side that is why it doesn't generate the correct query.

What you need is [`Queryable.Where`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535040.aspx) method which accepts a `Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> predicate`

So change you `Find` method signature to:

```
public virtual TEntity Find(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
{
    return _tEntities.Where(predicate).FirstOrDefault();
}
```